# Left and right side Databand on Fast Report Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastreport

i wanna set two DetailData left and right side on Fast Report Page , like this

### Header

```
   DetailData1                           |      Detail Data2
                                         |                                    
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
```

Footer 1_______________________________| Footer 2_____________________________________

---

how to make it that way, I can not change the width of detaildata ?
Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use subreports.
See FRDemo "Basic reports" section "Side-by-side subreports" report

Comment: Ok @gpi, i'll try . Thanx